# Validate all form data before submitting

Tags: javascript, html, forms, servlets

I have created a form in HTML and have use onblur event on each and every field and it is working very fine. The problem is when i click on submit button(which will send data to a servlet) the data is submitted even if it is invalid. Here is an example.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function check()
{
    if(checkName()==true)
        return true;
    else{
        alert('vhvh');
        return false;
    }
}
function checkName()  
{   
    var uname=document.enq.Name.value;
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z, ]+$/;  
    if(uname.match(letters))  
    {   
        document.getElementById('Name').style.borderColor = "black";
        return true;
    }  
    else  
    {  
        document.getElementById('Name').style.borderColor = "red";
        //alert('Username must have alphabet characters only');  
        //uname.focus();  
        return false;
    }  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="enq" method="post" action="Enquiry" onsubmit="check()">
<input class="textbox" id="Name"style="margin-top:10px;font-size:16px;" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Full Name" onblur="checkName()" required /><br><br>
<input class="button" type="submit"> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is an "onsubmit" event that allows you to control form submission. Use it to call your validation functions, and only then decide if you want to allow the user to submit the form.
http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_FORM_onSubmit.html

You have to use it in the following way if you want it to prevent the form submission:

```
<form onsubmit="return check()">
```

Comment: thanks @Ni. Now i have created a function that will check if the data is valid or not and it is working quite well. But still how i can restrict it from submitting data to servlet. Here is the code of my new method.
function check()
{
 if(checkName()==true && checkNumber()==true && ValidateEmail()==true)
  alert('true');
 else
  alert('false');
}

Comment: @ParveenKumar if the function returns false, the form will not be submitted.

Comment: @ParveenKumar I changed the link in my answer to a better site

Comment: It is not wokring, even on returning false it is submitting the data.

Comment: Please add the new code to your question so I could help

Comment: I have changed the code not the question please check

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ni. you were very helpful and BTW it worked :)

Comment: Great :) if It's the answer you were looking for you should choose it to mark the question as answered

Answer (score 0):

use

> `<input class="button" type="button">`

and put a onclick event like this:

> `<input class="button" type="button" onclick="this.submit()">`

so you can manipulate data before you subimit it.